# Declare recursive/multidimensional map

Tags: go

```
type Table struct {
    input map[string]map[string]
}
```

How to declare a multidimensional or recursive map?

```
input["var1"]["var2"] = "something"
```

## update

```
type Table struct {
    input map[map[string]]
}
```

returns error

```
 syntax error: unexpected ]
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You're looking for `map[string]map[string]string`. The problem with your example is it's missing the type of the value in the inner map. Here's an example of how to init such a structure;

```
m := map[string]map[string]string{
        "a": map[string]string{
            "1":"A",
            "2": "B",
        },
        "b": map[string]string{
            "1": "C",
            "2": "D",
        },
    }
```

Or following your example;

```
func main() {
        m := map[string]map[string]string{}
        m["var1"] = map[string]string{}
        m["var1"]["var2"] = "something"
        fmt.Println(m["var1"]["var2"])
}
```

That prints something.

Comment: @clarkk yeah mb, didn't mean to post that just yet. It's updated.

Comment: @clarkk BTW, given it's a little tricky/annoying to use such a nested map (you need to `make(map[string]string)` or equiv. each outer map value) also consider if you can instead use `type key struct {key1, key2 string}; map[key]string` for your purposes.

Comment: I'm trying to avoid making a struct for my case, because it's one-time usage on a single route; not used throughout the app. I'd rather not clutter my structs with something like this.